# Unable to initialize device PRN message upon executing .rb-Script in cygwin

Tags: ruby, windows, printing, cygwin

The headline should pretty much say it all. I'm using windows 7, installed cygwin, set it up, created a .rb-File which looks like this:

```
print "Test"
```

(Impressive stuff, eh?)

Now, using Cygwin, I want to execute it, I tried

```
chmod +x ruby.rb
```

afterwards

```
./ruby.rb
```

The following message comes up:

```
Unable to initialize device PRN
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the "she-bang" line. Without it it will be interpreted as a bash script, not a ruby script.

The print command that bash finds is Window's print.exe, which wants to print to a physical priner, rather than print to the screen.

Add "#!/usr/bin/env ruby" as the first line of the file.

Comment: Oh well, that was quick and painless, I just assumed I wouldn't need that considering that I'm just using Cygwin and not really working with the actual shell. Thanks!

Comment: Not working with the actual shell? But Cygwin is running the actual Born Again Shell (Bash). It does not know about file extensions any more than Bash on Linux does, with the special exception that Cygwin allows running exe files without explicitly typing the exe.